# Push from Azure repository to cpanel private repository

Tags: azure, repository, devops, push, pipeline

I'm trying to find a way to use a pipeline to push the Azure repository to another repository on my cpanel server. At the moment I'm just transfering the files over FTP but I need a proper push to activate autodeploy on cpanel repo.
Many thanks to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 0):

This process would be the same the way to commit changes to a git repository.

Initialize a git repository add the data in the staging area commit changes to local git repository then push the changes to remote git repository. The process isn't different from the normal local machine one.

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin <azure repo url >
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand, but the remote repository is private and I need to use SSH to push to repository. That is the problem since o don't know how to do that in azire